# What are these Internet Explorer parameters

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

Any idea what this command line does in Internet Explorer?

Why would it be running on my work laptop when I only ever use Chrome?

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:23528
> CREDAT:75014 /prefetch:2

Comment: Are you asking why Internet Explorer 11 is using your processor or trying to understand your processor usage for overall?

Comment: I just want to know what the command line does

Comment: And why it's running on my laptop

Comment: They are documented, well CREDAT is undocumented, SCODEF is most likely the PID. How exactly did you find this command?

Comment: I found it using using Process Explorer on my laptop. I haven't been able to find much documentation, apart from them being for internal Microsoft use only. In the question I 'duplicated' there's a link to a blog post describing them, but the link is broken

Comment: They are literally undocumented that’s why you can’t find information on them, please note, I did not vote to close your question.